# Ruby on Rails: paperclip error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I have a form that contains a file upload field named "application_path". I installed "Paperclip" GEM. But when i simply submit my form without selecting any file then i get error

```
undefined method `application_path_file_name' for #<ApplicationInstance:0x0000000561bc28>
```

Here are my request parameters shown in that error page

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"p3Y0SZT6wIonrrnzughybh8hywnkE1i3uBnxwrU4u9w=",
 "application_instance"=>{"device_id"=>"",
 "application_version_profile_id"=>""},
 "commit"=>"Create Application instance"}
```

The above parameter does not contain "application_path" with blank value. 
Here is my Model

```
class ApplicationInstance < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :application_version_profile_id, :device_id, :is_deleted, :application_path

  # Validations  
  validates :application_version_profile_id, :presence => true  
  validates :device_id, :presence => true
  validates_attachment_presence :application_path                    
  validates_attachment_size :application_path, :less_than=>1.megabyte
```

What i am missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the line that sets up paperclip for `ApplicationInstance`.  in your `application_instance.rb`

```
has_attached_file :application_path, styles: { medium: '300x300>', thumb: '100x100>' }
```

You may also be missing the required columns for paperclip which you can generate by

```
rails g paperclip application_instance application_path
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I would like to know if this is possible to perform custom operation like delete file from the same folder location before uploading a new file using paperclip?

Comment: do you want to overwrite the file?  i'm not really sure how that should work but you can delete the file by using `FileUtils.rm(application_instance.application_path.path)`

Answer (score 2):

Following link may help you
[Upload image using paperclip in Rails](http://gkunwar1.wordpress.com/2012/06/25/how-to-upload-file-using-paperclip-in-rails/)

Comment: Somehow i am able to upload files but when i added the code in the model validates_format_of :application_path, :with => %r{\.(txt)$}i where "application_path" is the my field name then i got error "Application path is invalid" even i am trying to upload text file....any idea?